What are sys-* project in GCP
I want to understand what sys-* projects that are shown in GCp. how these are created, how they are different from standard project that user create. Is there any property which can differentiate them?

From https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/admin/view-cloud-projects#view_or_edit_default :

If you only have resourcemanager.projects.list permission, standard and default projects show up together in one list. Default project IDs start with sys-

Also this question can give some understanding:
correlate GCP sys- with GCP project
